# filter's parameters in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I need an explanation to understand what are the filter's parameters in the below Angular code, i.e. what are x, idx, and xs. The *distinct* function below gets a list of products and returns a list of distinctive categories. My problem is understanding the filter parameters, i.e. *x*, *idx*, and *xs*.

```
const distinct = data => data
  .map(x => x.Category)
  .filter((x, idx, xs) => xs.findIndex(y => y.CategoryName === x.CategoryName) === idx);
```

The *distinct* method gets a list as below:

```
[
{
    "ProductID": 1,
    "ProductName": "Chai",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 1,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "10 boxes x 20 bags",
    "UnitPrice": 18,
    "UnitsInStock": 39,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
    "ReorderLevel": 10,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    },
    "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 20)
},
{
    "ProductID": 2,
    "ProductName": "Chang",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 1,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "24 - 12 oz bottles",
    "UnitPrice": 19,
    "UnitsInStock": 17,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 40,
    "ReorderLevel": 25,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    },
    "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 7, 12)
},
{
    "ProductID": 3,
    "ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 2,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles",
    "UnitPrice": 10,
    "UnitsInStock": 13,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 70,
    "ReorderLevel": 25,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 2,
        "CategoryName": "Condiments",
        "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 26)
},
{
    "ProductID": 4,
    "ProductName": "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
    "SupplierID": 2,
    "CategoryID": 2,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "48 - 6 oz jars",
    "UnitPrice": 22,
    "UnitsInStock": 53,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
    "ReorderLevel": 0,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 2,
        "CategoryName": "Condiments",
        "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 9, 19)
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can actually look at filter's type:

```
filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => any, thisArg?: any): T[];
```

So first you get a list of Category, and the values in the filter function are:

```
value = category element
index = index of the element
array = Category list (the one you get from the map)
```

Answer (score 0):

x is the value of the object itself 
idx is the index of the current item array[idx] 
and xs is the array map